# How can i merge columns of one table with columns of other table and store it in other table?

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

I have DataTable FirstTable which have column "Sno, Name, Batch". I need the datas of column Name only and i need to merge it in other table(for eg table named as NewTable). NewTable already have some datas. And also i have second table which have column "AccountNo, Name, City". I want to replace the "Name" column values of second table with Name column values of NewTable. I need to do this in cs file.

```
My First Table

SNo    Name    Batch

1      Name1    Batch1

2      Name2    Batch2

3      Name3    Batch3

4      Name4    Batch4


 NewTable

Name

Name5 

Name6 


Second Table

AccountNo    Name    City

1            Name8    City1

2            Name9    City2

3            Name10    City3

4            Name11    City4



After Merging FirstTable "Name" column with NewTable


Name

Name1 

Name2 

Name3 

Name4 

Name5 

Name6 



After Merging NewTable "NewName" column with "NewName" column of second table

AccountNo    Name    City

1            Name1    City1

2            Name2    City2

3            Name3    City3

4            Name4    City4

             Name5    

             Name6
```

Comment: What did you try (besides asking us?) ?

Comment: i tried Merge method to merge table, but Merge method merging whole table. I want to merge Name columns only. So i cant use Merge method.

Comment: your question is still very unclear, and your sample doesn't clarify much